# Response.CacheControl not working in firefox or chrome

Tags: asp.net, caching, response

i have this code in global.asax.vb, to disable the back button.

```
Sub Application_BeginRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Response.Buffer = True
    Response.ExpiresAbsolute = Now().Subtract(New TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0))
    Response.Expires = -1
    Response.CacheControl = "no-cache"
End Sub
```

this code works perfect in IE, but refuses to work in any other browser like firefox or chrome. what can i do to make it multi browser?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to refer to [this article](http://blog.httpwatch.com/2008/10/15/two-important-differences-between-firefox-and-ie-caching/). The answer it gives is to use both "no-cache" (for IE) and "no-store" (for Firefox). The reason for using "no-store" is because: "The lack of no-cache support is limited to early versions of Firefox 3.0 and was cause by a bug. Although, no-cache alone should now work it is possible that visitors to your site will be running affected versions of Firefox."